Remove top left drop down button when JInternalFrameMinimize
Problem image:

No problem image:

I am using JInternalFrame and to remove the dropdown list at the top left of the frame, since it serves no purpose, I use this code (the result is in the image):
    public static void customizeInternalFrameUI(JInternalFrame internalFrame) {
        // Remove the top left button of the dropdown menu
        BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI) internalFrame.getUI();
        Container north = (Container) ui.getNorthPane();
        north.remove(0);
        north.validate();
        north.repaint();
    }

When I expand the window again, there is no button (the code I gave in the first case works always).
I want to remove the dropdown list in the upper left corner of the frame, since it doesn't serve to minimize the window (the result is in image #2). How I make this?
I use event formFrameIconified and another event. Not results.

Setting an icon with a height of zero with the JInternalFrame#setFrameIcon(Icon) method may work.

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class InternalFrameIconTest {
  private Component makeUI() {
    JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    JInternalFrame f1 = makeInternalFrame();
    f1.setLocation(40, 40);
    desktop.add(f1);
    JInternalFrame f2 = makeInternalFrame();
    f2.setLocation(10, 10);
    desktop.add(f2);
    return desktop;
  }

  private static JInternalFrame makeInternalFrame() {
    JInternalFrame f = new JInternalFrame("", true, true, false, true);
    f.setFrameIcon(new HorizontalStrutIcon(16));
    f.setSize(240, 120);
    f.setVisible(true);
    return f;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return;
      }
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new InternalFrameIconTest().makeUI());
      frame.setSize(320, 240);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}

class HorizontalStrutIcon implements Icon {
  private final int width;

  public HorizontalStrutIcon(int width) {
    this.width = width;
  }

  @Override public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    // empty
  }

  @Override public int getIconWidth() {
    return width;
  }

  @Override public int getIconHeight() {
    return 0;
  }
}

